# Помогите с запятой 13

Tags: пунктуация

Не могу понять ставится ли запятая в этом случае, даже если главное слово в причастном обороте употреблено не в И.п?

**Скажем так: я не умею формулировать мысли в той степени(,) которой необходимо, чтобы вести полноценную жизнь.**

Comment: _**"...в причастном обороте"**_ === А где вы увидели причастный оборот?

Answer (score 2):

Желательно исправить предложение:

Скажем так: я не умею формулировать мысли в той степени, которая необходима, чтобы вести полноценную жизнь.

Comment: Грамматически я бы точно так же исправил это предложение; хотел было улучшить его по смыслу и стилю (Скажем так: я не умею формулировать мысли в степени, достаточной для полноценного общения.), но подумалось, что привитая "правильность выражения мыслей" будет противоречить содержанию предложения - оно ведь от первого лица :)

Answer (score 0):

Здесь не только запятую нужно проставить, но и предлог повторить.

*Скажем так: я не умею формулировать мысли в той степени, **в** которой необходимо, чтобы вести полноценную жизнь.*

"Причастного оборота" тут нет, есть обособленное определение, вводимое союзным словом, местоименным прилагательным "который". Никаких оговорок на падеж "главного слова" правила вообще не предполагают.

Ну а без союза тут совершенно не воспринимается связь с основной частью. Да и вообще предложный падеж без предлога в современном русском - нонсенс.

(+)
Посмотрел другой ответ. Фраза выглядит несколько канцелярской (именно из-за оборота "в той..., в которой"), но не настолько, чтобы её обязательно править и дальше. Хотя конечно, нет предела совершенству.